# How to group_by a factor and take majority column values for multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, lapply

I have a COVID-19 policies dataset with a date column and many columns with dummy variables. The exact data I'm using is the following:

```
IRPP_Index <- tbl_df(read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charlesbreton/COVID19-Canada-Provinces/master/Data/Canada-COVID19-Stringency.csv"))

IRPP_Index$date <- ymd(IRPP_Index$date)
IRPP_Index[is.na(IRPP_Index)] <- 0
        
BC_IRPP <- IRPP_Index %>%
              filter(Province.Territory=="British Columbia") %>%
              select(date, S1_Gathering, S3_Schools, S5_Care.home.visitation, 
                     S6_Dining.and.restaurants, S7_Non.essential.retail.business, 
                     S8_Non.essential.services, S9_Cultural.services.and.venues, S10_Intra.Travel,
                     S11_Inter.Travel, S12_Curfew, stringencyIndex) %>%
                     ## Omit Masks in public, Masks in schools
              select(date, stringencyIndex, S1_Gathering:S12_Curfew) %>%
              mutate_at(vars(S1_Gathering:S12_Curfew), as.character) %>%
              fastDummies::dummy_cols() %>%
              select(date, stringencyIndex, S1_Gathering_0:S12_Curfew_0)
    BC_IRPP$week <- floor_date(BC_IRPP$date, "week")
```

I hope to now group by the week column generated and for each week take the majority observation within the dummy variables.  The following operation using count() and top_n() will do this for a single column, but I'm having trouble with applying such a computation over all the columns in the data frame.

```
BC_IRPP <- BC_IRPP %>%
                      select(-date) %>%
                      group_by(week) %>%
                      count(S1_Gathering_0) %>%
                      top_n(1)
```

A method that comes to mind is an lapply() operation with multiple functions, being count() and top_n().

Comment: please provide code for your data, not paths. maybe dput(head(IRPP_Index), 15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method by reshaping longer, selecting mode, and reshaping wide again.

```
library(tidyverse)
BC_IRPP %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(date:stringencyIndex, week)) %>%
  group_by(week, name) %>%
  count(value, sort = T) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Answer (score 1):

`{dplyr}` comes with the `across()` function to work on (scoped) columns of your dataframe/tibble.

In your case you operate on your observation (columns), thus we can define a function that identifies the maximum observation.
There are many ways to do this, let's use another cool package `{vctrs}` and here the function `vec_count()`.

```
library(vctrs)

# ------------- check what vec_count does ---------------
c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1) %>% 
   vec_count()

# returns data frame with key and count ordered by count, i.e. max key is first element
#  key count
#1   1     7
#2   0     6

# -------------- define our helper function --------------
extract_max <- function(.vec){
   my_max <- .vec %>% vec_count()
   my_max <- my_max$key[1]   # extract max key
}
```

We can now plug this into `across()`.

```
# ------------- give it a try with a single observation column
BC_IRPP %>% 
    select(week, S1_Gathering_0) %>% 
    group_by(week) %>% 
    summarise(across( .cols = contains("S1_")  # limit this to S1 vars for demo, adapt for full data set
                     , .fns = extract_max
             )
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 64 x 2
   week       S1_Gathering_0
   <date>              <int>
 1 2020-03-01              1
 2 2020-03-08              1
 3 2020-03-15              0
 4 2020-03-22              0
 5 2020-03-29              0
```

Putting all together now and applying across over all relevant columns
For this you remove the limiting `select()` call and adapt the `contains()` helper.
For demo purposes, I continue to restrict the solution to your `S1_xxx` columns.

```
BC_IRPP %>% 
   group_by(week) %>% 
   summarise(across(.cols = contains("S1_")  # still restricting demo to S1 vars
                                             # will result in the 5 S1_xxx columns
                   , .fns = extract_max
   ))
```

Voila:

```
# A tibble: 64 x 5
   week       S1_Gathering_0 S1_Gathering_2 S1_Gathering_4 S1_Gathering_5
   <date>              <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
 1 2020-03-01              1              0              0              0
 2 2020-03-08              1              0              0              0
 3 2020-03-15              0              0              1              0
 4 2020-03-22              0              0              1              0
 5 2020-03-29              0              0              1              0
 6 2020-04-05              0              0              1              0
 7 2020-04-12              0              0              1              0
 8 2020-04-19              0              0              1              0
 9 2020-04-26              0              0              1              0
10 2020-05-03              0              0              1              0
```

`across()` is a powerful call with `mutate()` or `summarise()`. It might take a while to sort out the wiring for more complex operations on the vector/column. Here it helps - at least me - to define the helper function outside the `across()` call.